# Can I use destructuring somehow inside an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, destructuring

is there a way I could do something like this ?

```
if({color, size, shape} = this.props){
  console.log('Received all props!');
} else {
  console.log('There are some missing props');
}
```

I want to know if I received all needed data through my Component's props,
and if not then throw an error.

It's for creating reusable components.

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: you can't check for the truthiness of multiple properties like that

Comment: Why don’t you just extract the props before the if and check them like a regular vars? I don’t see what will you earn using the proposed way...

Comment: OK I know it's a bit longer but since you seem to know the props you expect why not just: `if (['color','shape','size'].join(',') === Object.keys(this.props).sort().join(',')`

Comment: @Coluccini
I'm using react, and I thought to check before render my component if all needed props was receieved.

and if i do destructuring of one or more undefined props then my functions will break.

Sure I can write a long version validation, but I wanted to know if I can shorten my code with some destructuring inside the if statement

Comment: React is completely irrelevant

Comment: This is definitely one of those cases where trying to be 'clever' and reduce the number of lines will cause debugging pain down the line

Comment: @ueeiee what I mean is that to achieve something like you proposed you need to know the expected props, so you can simple do it likes this:

`const { color, size, shape } = this.props;`
`if(color && size && shape){`
But maybe I'm missing something…

Comment: @Coluccini you're right, my example of using react and extractinv props wasnt so good here. 

for a moment i was mistakening to think that if you try to declare those props with destructuring when you dont actually have them you break the life cycle, but you just get undefined. my mistake :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use default values:

```
function missing(prop) {
    throw new TypeError(`there is a missing ${prop} property`);
}

…
try {
  const {
    color = missing("color"),
    size = missing("size"),
    shape = missing("shape"),
  } = this.props;
  // use color, size, shape here
  console.log("Received all props!");
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

To use an `if` statement, no you cannot use destructuring to produce a boolean whether all properties are there. Rather do something usual as

```
if ("color" in this.props && "size" in this.props && "shape" in this.props) {
  console.log('Received all props!');
} else {
  console.log('There are some missing props');
}
```

(or better yet, check for the type of the value that you expected)