# how to throw error for destructuring non-existent key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I'd like to destructure an object and have it throw an error if one of the keys didn't exist. I tried a `try catch` but it didn't work. And I'd like an alternative to just `if (variable === undefined)`

```js
let obj = {test : "test"}

try {
 let { test, asdf } = obj 
  console.log("worked")
}
catch (error) {
 console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47744416/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to throw the error if a non-existent property is fetched

```
let obj = {
  test: "test"
};

try 
{
    let { test, asdf} = getProxy(obj);
    console.log("worked");
} 
catch (error) 
{
    console.error(error)
}

function getProxy(obj) {
    return new Proxy(obj, { //create new Proxy object
        get: function(obj, prop) { //define get trap
            if( prop in obj )
            {
               return obj[prop];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Error("No such property exists"); //throw error if prop doesn't exists
            }            
        }
    });
}
```

**Demo**

```js
let obj = {
  test: "test"
};

try 
{
    let { test, asdf} = getProxy(obj);
    console.log("worked");
} 
catch (error) 
{
    console.error(error)
}

function getProxy(obj) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get: function(obj, prop) {
            if( prop in obj )
            {
               return obj[prop];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Error("No such property exists");
            }            
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try-catch` work for the `runtime` errors, catching exceptions or error you throw explicitly. Thus, in destructuring, there is no such error thrown when the matching key is not found. To check the existence you need to explicitly create a check for it. Something like this,

```js
let obj = {test : "test"}
let { test, asdf } = obj 

if(test){
 console.log('worked');
} else {
 console.log('not worked');
}

if(asdf){
 console.log('worked');
} else {
 console.log('not worked');
}
```

This is because the destructuring works the same way as we assign the object value to another value like,

```
let obj = {test : "test"}
var test = obj.test;
var asdf = obj.asdf;
```

Here, doing `obj.asdf` will give you `undefined` in `asdf` and does not throw any exception. Thus, you cannot use `try-catch` for that.

Comment: yeah but I was really trying to avoid the all `variable === undefined` check since it means I would have to check all of them.

Comment: @A.Lau indeed, yes